# Change div style inside iframe react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe, next.js

I am working in a next js project and have implemented an iframe inside a component. Problem is I want to change the style of the div inside the iframe which loads after the iframe is rendered in the component. I am unable to select the div with id "embed" inside the iframe.
[image]

Is there any way to select the div in react ? I have tried using contentWindow and still its not working.

Comment: what an error you found ?

Comment: Suppose if i write "const node = document.getElementById("maya_chat").contentWindow;
const element = node.document.getElementById("embed");" and console element I get undefined.

Comment: Do you have the correct rights to access the iframe? Is it hosted on your domain or someone elses?

Comment: obviously you cant add other component inside iframe. Because is a different sites.

Comment: @cloned : It is hosted on different domain. Thanks

Comment: @Fiido93: Right. Thanks

Comment: Don't post codes as screenshot

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the content of an iframe if the document in the iframe is from a different domain. This is by design.

Read about Cross-origin script API access on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_script_api_access